# Touchpad edge scrolling not working on upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lenovo, scrolling

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and now I can't use edge scrolling on my laptop's touchpad! Why is this happening?! A few hours back everything was fine in 13.04. Is this a bug? Any workarounds available?

PS: My laptop is a Lenovo G570 with Intel Core i5 @ 2.3GHz

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason is that **two finger scroll** has been enabled by default in Ubuntu 13.10. In case you want to get back the edge scrolling, do the following:

- Go to Unity Dash and look for **Mouse & Touchpad**
- In here, **uncheck** the **Two finger scroll** option

That's it. No need to restart or anything. Edge scrolling will be back. Here is a tutorial I wrote, in case you need screenshots: [Enable edge scrolling in Ubuntu 13.10](http://itsfoss.com/enable-edge-scrolling-ubuntu-1310-quick-tip/).

Comment: Also related, the `natural scrolling` option in the same window allows you to use the scrollpad in the opposite direction, like a Mac touchpad.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, caused by two-finger scrolling being enabled by default. Go to the power/settings icon, select system settings, select mouse and touchpad, and deselect two finger scroll.